How to join skirt to LOD terrain mesh chunk to ensure it matches at seams?
I am exporting my Unity terrain to a mesh. Because the terrain is big, I also split it into multiple chunks.
Moreover, I also generate chunk LODs. I enable a certain chunk LOD in-game based on the player's distance to that chunk.
The issue is that I get gaps when two chunks that are in different LOD levels try to connect. So I essentially need for every lower than LOD_0 chunk mesh to have a border that is the density of the LOD_0 mesh.
https://i.imgur.com/AcWxzMU.png
I have started writing the new mesh generation code, and this is what I have so far:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Sirenix.OdinInspector;
using Unity.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshStitchGeneration : MonoBehaviour
{
    private struct BorderData : IDisposable
    {
        public NativeList<Vector3> borderVertices;
        public NativeList<int>     borderTriangles;

        public static BorderData Null => default;

        public BorderData(Allocator allocator)
        {
            borderVertices = new(allocator);
            borderTriangles = new(allocator);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            borderVertices.Dispose();
            borderTriangles.Dispose();
        }
    }

    [SerializeField] private Mesh lod0Mesh     = null;
    [SerializeField] private Mesh lowerLODMesh = null;
    [SerializeField] private Material material = null;

    [Button("Generate")]
    private void Generate()
    {
        var newObj = new GameObject("Generated");
        
        newObj.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);

        newObj.transform.SetLocalPositionAndRotation(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

        var filter = newObj.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        var renderer = newObj.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

        renderer.sharedMaterial = material;

        using var borderMeshData = GetBorderMeshData();
        var newStitchedMesh = AppendBorderDataToMesh(in borderMeshData);

        filter.sharedMesh = newStitchedMesh;
    }

    private BorderData GetBorderMeshData()
    {
        if (lod0Mesh == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No lod0Mesh assigned!");

            return BorderData.Null;
        }

        var bound = lod0Mesh.bounds;

        if (bound.size.x != bound.size.z)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Requires a square mesh!");

            return BorderData.Null;
        }

        var vertices = lod0Mesh.vertices.AsSpan();
        var triangles = lod0Mesh.triangles.AsSpan();

        var gridSize = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.Sqrt(vertices.Length));
        var vertexIncrement = bound.size.x / (gridSize - 1);

        var data = new BorderData(Allocator.Persistent);
        var vertexIndexMapping = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 vertex = vertices[i];

            var ox = bound.min.x;
            var oz = bound.min.z;

            if (vertex.x < ox + bound.size.x - vertexIncrement
                && vertex.z < oz + bound.size.z - vertexIncrement
                && vertex.x > ox + vertexIncrement * 2
                && vertex.z > oz + vertexIncrement * 2)
            {
                continue;
            }

            vertexIndexMapping[i] = data.borderVertices.Length;
            data.borderVertices.Add(vertex);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3)
        {
            int v1 = triangles[i];
            int v2 = triangles[i + 1];
            int v3 = triangles[i + 2];

            bool isV1OnBorder = vertexIndexMapping.ContainsKey(v1);
            bool isV2OnBorder = vertexIndexMapping.ContainsKey(v2);
            bool isV3OnBorder = vertexIndexMapping.ContainsKey(v3);

            if (isV1OnBorder || isV2OnBorder || isV3OnBorder)
            {
                if (isV1OnBorder) data.borderTriangles.Add(vertexIndexMapping[v1]);
                if (isV2OnBorder) data.borderTriangles.Add(vertexIndexMapping[v2]);
                if (isV3OnBorder) data.borderTriangles.Add(vertexIndexMapping[v3]);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    private Mesh AppendBorderDataToMesh(in BorderData borderData)
    {
        if (lowerLODMesh == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No lowerLODMesh assigned!");
            return null;
        }
        var newMesh = new Mesh();

        var lowerVertices = lowerLODMesh.vertices;
        var lowerTriangles = lowerLODMesh.triangles;

        var combinedVertices  = new List<Vector3>(lowerVertices.Length + borderData.borderVertices.Length);
        var combinedTriangles = new List<int>(lowerTriangles.Length + borderData.borderTriangles.Length);

        combinedVertices.AddRange(lowerVertices);

        foreach (var borderVertex in borderData.borderVertices)
        {
            combinedVertices.Add(borderVertex);
        }
        combinedTriangles.AddRange(lowerTriangles);

        int lowerVertexCount = lowerVertices.Length;

        foreach (var triangleIndex in borderData.borderTriangles)
        {
            combinedTriangles.Add(lowerVertexCount + triangleIndex);
        }
        newMesh.vertices  = combinedVertices.ToArray();
        newMesh.triangles = combinedTriangles.ToArray();

        newMesh.RecalculateNormals(); newMesh.RecalculateBounds();

        return newMesh;
    }
}

The above code is currently just for testing so I apologize if it is not the best in quality. What I am doing right now is getting a border from the LOD_0 chunk mesh. That part is working great. Now I need to merge that border data with the lower LOD chunk mesh.
Currently what I have done inside the "AppendBorderDataToMesh" function just simply creates a new mesh that contains the border mesh and the chunk mesh. So just two meshes in one.
So like it can be seen in this image: https://i.imgur.com/Nkii36k.png
But that is not what I need. I want to create new triangles that connect the border mesh to the chunk mesh by essentially forming quads between the vertices of the border and the closest edge vertices of the chunk mesh.
So something like this I guess: https://i.imgur.com/gs9ko1y.png
This is quite complex and I am not sure how to do it.
Can someone please help me? Would really appreciate it

Some thoughts: 1. Have you tried to simply position your LOD_1 meshes lower than you're LOD_0 meshes, LOD_2 lower than LOD_1 etc? This is the cheap technique to avoid visible gaps that may work if the distance from camera is enough 2. I can imagine long triangles in your last image to cause visual artifacts (corrugation-like) when the border is not smooth 3.Have you tried to adjust LOD_0 border to LOD_1 border in realtime? New triangles not needed, only y positions need to be adjusted. Can be done async in multiple frames.


It is possible to split LOD_0 into 5 meshes, big center and 4 thin borders, and have the borders in two versions, original and the one stitched to LOD_1 border, and load them accordingly.

